# jquery why can I set position of one label but not the other?

Tags: jquery, css, position, label

Check this JS fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jclamp/Nf7Fc/3/

The label for Name is creted via jquery and it's position can then be set using it's parent field's position.

The label for email is created via form validation. The same jquery should be able to set it's position but it doesn't. Why?

Works:

```
$('#name').after('<label class="error" for="name">I can create this label via jquery and then move it\'s position.</label><br>');

$('label.error').css('left', 
                     function() {
                    return $('input[name='+$(this).attr('for')+']' ).offset().left;
                     } 
                      );
```

Doesn't work:

```
$("#registerForm").validate();

$('label.error').css('left', 
                     function() {
                    return $('input[name='+$(this).attr('for')+']' ).offset().left;
                     } 
                      );
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use CSS? Using jQuery's .css() method is like using a stylesheet.

Comment: Try to use DOMSubtreeModified event on form element to update dynamically created labels

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @FriederikeS Because I need to find the label's parent field and use it's position to set the label's field. I can control the javascript and css of this application but can't change the html such that I could create container divs for field/label combo.

Comment: @CTAPbIu_MABP seems like that is deprecated and has limited browser support. Hmm.. Maybe a setinterval? bleh. Someone feel free to poast an answer so I can accept :)

Comment: @JaseClamp it supported by all major browser (ie >= 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
    $('label.error').css('left', function() {
        // find input element assigned to the label
        var inputName = $(this).prop('for'); // <--- here
        var inputElement = $('input[name=' + inputName + ']' );

        // you can use logging to see which element jQuery actually found:
        console.log(inputElement);

        return inputElement.offset().left;
    });
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JjYPR/3/

Hope this helps.

I have some notes on your code though. The code in your jsfiddle was not working at all. There were some errors with names of the elements and when you pressed the submit button nothing was validated but another error occured. Next time you post a question you might keep the following tips in mind:

- Check errors using Firebug or some other debugging tool
- If you have a setting where your code works, create a jsfiddle that works too
- Try to indent your code to make it more readable

Then it is easier for people to help you. ;)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! The code was working but then I kept fiddling with it after I posted here. Shame on me. Thanks again for your help though.

Comment: For anyone who wants to simply absolute position jquery validate error labels under their corresponding field elements, this was the simple code I ended up using:                                                `errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     element.after( error.css('left',element.offset().left) . css('top',element.offset().top+45) );
      },`                                             using `invalidHandler` or `showErrors` did not work since the css adjustments only showed up on the second click of the submit button.